# Referencing a table in web2py before defining it

Tags: python, web2py

My code is the following im trying to assign a department to employees and also create a manager in a department table

```
db = DAL(lazy_tables=True)
db.define_table('employee',
            Field('fullname','string',label='Name'),
            Field('email','string'),
            Field('phone','string'),
            Field('kids', 'string'),
            Field('phone', 'string'),
            #Field('date','datetime'),
            Field('dob', 'datetime', label='Date'),
            Field('department', 'reference department',
                  requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.department.id, '%(department_name)s')),
            auth.signature,
            format='%(fullname)s'

            )
db = DAL(lazy_tables=True)
db.define_table('department',
            Field('department_name', 'string', label='Department Name'),
            # Field('department_name', 'string', label='Department Name'),
            Field('manager', 'reference employee', required='true',
                  requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.employee.id, '%(fullname)s')),
            auth.signature,
            format='%(department_name)s'
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the 2nd `db = DAL(lazy_tables=True)`, you should be fine.

The problem you have is that you essentially overwrote the first db object by declaring/instantiating it again after the first table definition (employee).

This gives you a new db object (with no tables defined) in which you define a table (department) that references another table (employee) that no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Field('department', 'reference department',
          requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.department.id, '%(department_name)s')),
```

In the above line, you reference `db.department.id`, but the `department` table has not yet been defined, so the `db` object will not yet have a `department` attribute.

You should instead be able to use this alternative syntax:

```
IS_IN_DB(db, 'department.id', '%(department_name)s')
```

Alternatively, you can define the `requires` attribute after defining the `department` table:

```
db.employee.department.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.department.id, '%(department_name)s')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DAL' object has no attribute 'employee' after doing it

Comment: i think the issue isnt the requires attribute because ive removed it and got another error;after adding the ' ' i got ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Based on your related posts in the Google Group, you have introduced two new errors in your code (not shown in your question above), so this is difficult to answer here.