# referencing a table which is defined after the definition of the first table in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

```
    db.define_table("devices",
            Field('user_id','reference users'),#   THIS PRODUCES AN ERROR 
            Field('energyConsumed','integer'),
            Field('device_password','password'),
            Field('date_of_measure','date')
            );
db.define_table("users",
            Field('device_id','reference devices')
);
```

I am unable to use 'reference users' in the first table because it has not been defined before that tables definition . How can I reference table which is defined only later on .

Comment: It's always best to report the exact error (preferably the whole traceback). As it is, your code should work -- is that the exact code, and are you sure that particular line is the one causing your error? Also, do you really need the circular reference? If you are trying to model a many-to-many relationship, you should instead have a third table linking the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not reference to table which is not defined. So you have to use alternative syntax.

Use `IS_IN_DB` validator for this.

```
IS_IN_DB(db, 'users.id')
```

This is already answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948788/4065350
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/yNca8bq0HmM/DmVjCPrODQAJ

Comment: This answer is not relevant in this case, as the code in the question does not include `db.users` anywhere (i.e., there is no attempt to access an undefined table).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a table that is not yet defined, but this is what I do, declaring the field as integer and referencing the table after define it.

```
db.define_table("devices",
    Field('user_id','integer'),
    Field('energyConsumed','integer'),
    Field('device_password','password'),
    Field('date_of_measure','date')
);
db.define_table("users",
    Field('device_id','reference devices')
);
db.devices.user_id.requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.users.id)
```